# Как сделать такую же анимацию,но через animation?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/geharka/pen/bGRVwVb

Нужно сделать так же работающую анимацию,но используя свойство `animation`.
Важно,чтоб при отсутствии наведения анимация возвращалась с начальному положению плавно, как будто она инвертирована, и идет от конца к началу.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 1s linear 1s, height 1s linear 0s;
}

.hover:hover {
  transition: width 1s linear 0s, height 1s linear 1s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover"></div>
```

Comment: Точно такого же с помощью чистых анимаций на CSS скорее всего не получится, но можно сделать через javascript

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.square{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    animation: square linear 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes square{
0%{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
25%{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
50%{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
80%{
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
}
100%{
    width: 100px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Простите,видимо неправильно сформулировал вопрос.Нужно, чтоб анимация работала при наведении,и плавно возвращалась в исходное положение при отсутствии наведения.Если брать в пример представленную вами анимацию,то нужно,чтоб при наведении анимация двигалась до 50%, а затем останавливалась.И как только курсор с элемента убирается,анимация должна дойти до 100%(или вернутся к началу). При этом,если курсор убран с элемента до того,как она дошла до 50%,то она должна пойти в обратном направлении,вернувшись к началу.